# Trouble allowing external connections in apache 2.4

Tags: internet, apache-http-server, port-forwarding

I am currently trying to host a html webpage to the internet using Apache 2.4 My issue is allowing outside connections to the server and it is beginning to be very frustrating for me. I believe I have configured the httpd.conf file correctly according to the documentation and port forwarding and firewall rules have been set correctly to my knowledge. I am thankful for any help Happy New Year!

Spec:

-Apache 2.4

-Windows 7

-Static IP

Things I have done:

-modifying the httpd.conf trying many different configs

-contacting isp(making sure no ports blocked)

-forwarding ports in router

-adding firewall rules in windows

Comment: What have you tried with httpd.conf and what are the results (error codes and messages) that you get when trying to access the web page?

Answer (score 0):

You should:

- Disable the firewall completely for testing. Otherwise, there still may be issues.
- Make sure the site is working (available if you type 127.0.0.1 in the browser of the host PC) and accessible to the local network (you can connect to the internal host IP with e.g. your smartphone browser when on wifi).
- Check your public site availability using the *fixed IP* (not the domain name) from an outside network (nothing going through your router, so use e.g. a 4G connection on your phone).
- Make sure that the IP your router connects to is publicly available (i.e. it is your fixed public IP, not an internal IP).

If you're sure your site is operating correctly, but fails otherwise, you can also try a service like [localtunnel](https://localtunnel.github.io/www/) (which relies on [Node.js](https://nodejs.org/en/)).